How to send variable by method result for Main
My problem consists of a Main() method that calls a static Future from another class/file, which has the function of doing a post/get in php and returns a "response.body", but after finishing the call, it returns to my Main and continues the process.
If I try to mention a variable, it always returns NULL, because the value is lost when returned to Main.
My problem is how to send the "response.body" to my main within a variable so that I can treat it and use it in other processes.
Below is a practical model of the problem.
Every result is a NULL variable
*file_1 -----------:*
void main(List<String> args) {
  
  var result;  

  method.test();
  print(result);
 
}

*file_2 -----------:*

class method {
static Future<String> test() async{
    var result = '1';
    return result;

  }
}


You've misunderstood the scope of variables.  You have two different variables called result which exist in two different scopes.  Setting one has no effect on the other.
The method is returning its result.  Which means that calling the method is an expression which resolves to that result.  That result is assignable to a variable like any other value:
void main(List<String> args) {
  var result = method.test();
  print(result);
}


Work for me, thanks!
